# Can't access resources on tomcat server

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee

I have created a simple [web-service](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-restful-web-service.html#run_config) in IntelliJ using tomcat.
I can't access the resources despite tomcat running without any error.

Tomcat configuration:
[image]

Code-

```
    @Path("/hello-world")
    public class HelloResource {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

Error-
[image]

What is the correct URL to see "Hello World" ?

Comment: Probably `http://localhost:8080/hello-world` ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any resources in the '/' path. Try `http://localhost:8080/hello-world`